Is 1rst a valid abbreviation for first?
At school I was taught to abbreviate first as 1rst. That was about 20 years ago in Germany, learning British English.
But I have not encountered anything other than 1st recently. I'm not even sure if I ever saw 1rst outside of class material. From a quick look over search results it doesn't seem to be a BE vs AE thing. Usage could have changed over the years, of course.
So - is 1rst an outdated/uncommon but valid abbreviation, or has it always been just 1st?

Searching around, it is hard to find clear examples from native speakers using 1rst.  I found some in sources from Canada, but these could be from French speaking Quebecois. I speculate that this might be an error of french speakers who use 1ere, and so expect a three letter suffix for 1st.  How this error got into German textbooks is anyone's guess.  But it is absolutely an error.  It is in no way "valid".

You were badly taught, obviously. But I'm surprised it took you 20 years to notice that native Anglophones effectively never use 1rst today, considering how often you most have encountered 1st over the years.

@FumbleFingers I don't think I've come across the abbreviation all that often. Mostly randomly across the internet, and considering how many regional differences there are and how usage can change over time it never seemed significant. Never mind the overall quality of much of that. But it's very, very rare compared to "first" or a numbered list in the type of things I read in English (the 21st century isn't mentioned a lot in fantasy novels or technical documentation). The trigger to actually look it up was that spellcheck complained about it in some messy meeting notes.

Yeah, I doubt the "21rst century" would crop up much in fantasy novels. But 1st, 2nd, or 3rd might. As that chart shows, all those abbreviations were much more common a century or two ago But @JamesK's point re "french speakers who use 1ere" is bang on the money for me. I looked at some written instances of 1rst - all 10 on the 1st page were either french or canadian.

Never seen 1rst in the UK either and I've also spent a reasonable amount of time reading old railway documents. never seen 1rst in a date that I've noticed and I've certainly gone much further back than the OP's twenty years!

Twenty years ago...2004, sounds a long time ago but it's not, especially if you're someone in their sixties :) Calendar dates? Never come across 31st October at  least in print?

I haven't seen "1rst", but I have seen "3d". That is older though, and only "3rd" is used nowadays, in line with 1st, 2nd and nth

@NoName, when I see "3d" I think "threepence" (3 pennies in pre-decimal UK currency).

@Peter Makes sense. But in context, it really was "third"

Native speaker of English here, with lots of grey hair.  I've never seen 1rst, and if I ever did see it, I'd assume that whoever wrote it was NOT a native speaker.  I think it's safe to say that your schoolteacher in Germany was simply wrong.

If I saw it in the wild, I would assume it was archaic -- I can find some very very old examples of it.

@Peter For the younger (by which I mean post-decimal, so hardly ‘younger’ anymore) crowd, I’d venture ‘three-dimensional’ would be the more obvious association, even if that is usually written 3D with a capital D.

I have only ever seen "1st", "2nd", "3rd", "4th" and so on in the UK. There are always two letters after the digit. Commonly, the two letters would be formatted as superscripts. Some of the word-processors and email programs automatically format these superscripts.
Google ngrams for "1rst" shows it has been used with a maximum of just less than 0.00000100% in about 1855. The ngram for both "1st" and "1rst" (see here) shows a minimum of about 0.0016% and maximum of nearly 0.02%. On the graph of both items, the "1rst" line appears flat and on zero.
My summary would be that "1rst" has been used but is very uncommon and it is dwarfed by the usage of "1st".

Same in the U.S.

There's also the calendar dates 21st and 31st

the letters are in general the last 2 1firST 99ninetyninTH

Thanks! While that has answered my question, I am now really wondering where my teacher picked that up. There is also a question on Quora by someone else who was taught both versions, so it wasn't a completely unique occurence. If I ever see him again, I will definitely ask :D I hope it's something more interesting than a typo in a (edition of a) textbook.

At the age of 7, speaking a lot of English and a little German, I was sent to a German primary school where I had to sit through English lessons, and the one thing I learnt was that teachers get a lot of things wrong.
